# Interface with a precompiled program

Tags: c++, console, iostream, interfacing

How do I take an already - compiled program (Console App) and communicate with it via my C++ code?
Such that "printing" into the program will be the same as a user that types what I print into the console of the program, and "reading" from it read what the program as written into the console?

Here is a pseudocode of what I want (preferably without external libraries):

```cpp
//also start (run) the program somehow
ProgramStream programStream = createStream("somepath/someprogram.exe")

programStream << "This will be written into the console of someprogram.exe" <<endl;

string result;
ProgramStream >> result; //gets what the program prints back
```

Comment: Boost.Process + Boost.Asio

Comment: @Evg isn't it an external ibrary?

Comment: It is. There is no standard way to do it.

Comment: Under Linux you can use PTYs and/or standard IOstream communication.

Comment: @Botje I use Windows

Comment: If you're using windows [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output?redirectedfrom=MSDN) might help.

Comment: @Evg how do I use this "boost" library?